# AngularJS using ng-model to insert into an array in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, mongodb

Currently, I am using ng-model to insert data into my MongoDB. Is there a way to use ng-model to insert data into an array in MongoDB? **answers** is an array that should contain 4 strings that the user enters. I tried adding [0], [1], [2], [3] to **quiz.quizData.answers** but it did not enter the data correctly as an array. Instead it entered it like this:

```
      "answers" : [ 
            {
                "0" : "My First Answer",
                "1" : "My Second Answer"
            }
],
```

instead of how it should be:

```
"answers" : [ 
    "My First Answer", 
    "My Second Answer"
],
```

**My HTML input form:**

```
<input type="text" name="answers" ng-model="quiz.quizData.answers" placeholder="enter answers here" required>
<input type="text" name="answers2" ng-model="quiz.quizData.answers" placeholder="enter other answers here" required>
```

**My End Point**

```
// POST request for users to post a new quiz entry
    apiRouter.route('/quiz')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        // Create quiz object and assign to 'quiz'
        var quiz = new Quiz();
        // Contains the quiz question
        quiz.question = req.body.question;
        // Contains an array with four quiz answers
        quiz.answers = req.body.answers;
        // Contains one string that matches the correct answer from the array above
        quiz.correctAnswer = req.body.correctAnswer;
        // Identifies user creating the quiz
        quiz.postedBy = req.body.postedBy;
        // Identifies the category of the quiz
        quiz.category = req.body.category;
        // then save new quiz to database
        quiz.save(function(err) {
            // If an error occurs, display error message in JSON format
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'something went way wrong....' + err });
            } else {
                // If no error occurs and it saves, display success
                res.json({ message: 'Quiz Created!' });
            }
        });
    });
```

**My MongoDB Schema:**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

// post schema 
var QuizSchema   = new Schema({
    question: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true },
    answers: { type: Array, required: true },
    correctAnswer: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true },
    postedBy: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Quiz', QuizSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **ng-repeat** iterating a range if you're starting with an empty array:

```
<input ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" type="text" name="answers{{i}}" ng-model="quiz.quizData.answers[i]" placeholder="enter answers here" required>
```

If your array already exists, and you want to account for variable array length you can use **ng-repeat** and **$index**.  Make sure you add **track by $index** or you will encounter an issue with duplicate keys:

```
<input ng-repeat="answer in quiz.quizData.answers track by $index" type="text" name="answers{{$index}}" ng-model="quiz.quizData.answers[$index]" placeholder="enter answers here" required>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/dwHIFTftgq5LFfTOpc9X?p=info

Comment: unfortunately, it created the exact same issue; it insert it as an object inside of an array, rather than four strings inside of an array

Comment: which option did you try?

Comment: If your array is already defined, it should work they should work.  For the first example, quiz.quizData.answers = [] will work.  Editing post to reflect this.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work the way you described. I was, however, able to figure out a work around. Not sure if it's a bad way of doing it, but it did accomplish what I wanted it to, so I guess it's better than nothing. What I did was create an array in the scope. Then, I put four separate input forms for the user, binding each one to the array I created in the scope. Then, i used ng-init to push that array into a hidden input that then submits it to the database.

Comment: Did you try the plunker I added to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="answer1" ng-model="answersArray[0]" placeholder="answer 1">
<input type="text" name="answer2" ng-model="answersArray[1]" placeholder="answer 2">
<input type="text" name="answer3" ng-model="answersArray[2]" placeholder="answer 3">
<input type="text" name="answer4" ng-model="answersArray[3]" placeholder="answer 4">
<input type="hidden" name="answers" ng-model="quiz.quizData.answers" placeholder="enter answers here" ng-init="quiz.quizData.answers = answersArray">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.answersArray = [
answer1 = $scope.answer1,
answer2 = $scope.answer2,
answer3 = $scope.answer3,
answer4 = $scope.answer4
];
```